# How to remove the last row of a table in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, sql-delete, dolphindb

Is there a way to remove the last row of a table in DolphinDB?

Take the following table as an example:

```
t = table(1..5 as id)
```

How can I remove the record with id=5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following method:

```
delete from t where rowNo(id) = size(t)-1
```

If you're working with a standard in-memory table, the alternatives are also helpful:

```
t[0:(size(t)-1)]
   
t.drop(-1)
```